# Spring JPA Hibernate object null when saving ManyToOne

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, crud

I have got two entities in bidirectional relation ( ManyToOne, OneToMany )
Two tables House & Room. House has many rooms.
I need to save house with it's address and two ( maybe later on more ) rooms.
The below code adds house and address without rooms ( room = null ).

How can I achieve this?

Does my inputs concerning rooms are ok? e.g in PHP I'll have 
`name="roomName[]"`

I thought that Hibernate will do everything for me :) especially when I use cascadeType.ALL

```
@Entity
@Data
public class House {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
  private PostalAddress address;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "house", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<Room> rooms;
}
```

**Room**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Room {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  private String name;

  @NotNull
  private int capacity;

  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "house_id")
  private House house;
}
```

**Create db entry Form**

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="house name..." />
<input type="text" name="address.addressLocality" placeholder="locality" />
<input type="text" name="address.postalCode" placeholder="postalCode" />
<input type="text" name="address.streetAddress" placeholder="street" />
<input type="text" name="room.name" placeholder="room name" />
<input type="text" name="room.capacity" placeholder="capacity" />
<input type="text" name="room.name" placeholder="room name" />
<input type="text" name="room.capacity" placeholder="capacity" />
```

**Finally my Controller and repository**

```
public interface RoomRepository extends CrudRepository<Room, Long> {
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveHouse(@ModelAttribute("house/new") House house, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

  houseRepository.save(house);

  return "redirect:/house/list";

}
```

// IMPORTANT EDIT

I've got tip what can be wrong but I can't resolve this. I'm using Thymeleaf. When House has Many Rooms ( Set rooms ) the part of the form that contains room inputs is incorrect. I'm displaying, by default, 4 rows ( room name, capacity ) in table

```
<tr th:each="i,iterStat : ${#numbers.sequence( 1, 4)}">
   <td class="col-xs-9 col-md-9"><input type="text" name="rooms.name" th:value="ROOM + ' ' + ${iterStat.current}"  class="form-control"/> </td>
   <td class="col-xs-2 col-md-2"><input type="number" name="rooms.capacity" min="1" step="1" value="4" class="form-control"/> </td>
   <td class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><button type="button" class="btn red pull-right" onclick="removeTableRow(this)"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </button></td>
</tr>
```

when user would like to add more or less rooms he ( using jQuery ) deletes/add table row with inputs
I was trying to change input name to

> th:field="*{rooms[**${iterStat.current}**].name}"

but this is not it. So how to populate these fields?

Comment: Are you getting room in your house object in RoomRepository saveHouse method?

Comment: Have you debugged the application, are there any rooms in the house which you save in the repository? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try House entity mapping with:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "house", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private PostalAddress address;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "house", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Room> rooms;
```

PostalAddress:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="house")
private House house;
```

Room:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="house")
private House house;
```

Comment: after applying your suggestions application is not saving anything giving nested exception. I guess that you try to change PostalAddress entity because of other (room,house) changes to avoid Hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy on PostalAddress. Basically I would prefer not to change something that works already - address of the house.

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood your problem. When you save with your version code - does House contains any Room?

Comment: I've marked braekpoint in houseRepository.save(house) and Room is null

Comment: I've also changed in form field name from room.name to rooms.name (this is my object in House Entity. Still null

Comment: So it's the problem with your form, not Hibernate cascading.

Comment: I've edited my question, I think that figured out what is my exact problem